# MYSQL trigger will trigger another one

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

I'm building a recycle bin like a windows trash can.
I have 3 tables.

when the parent table is deleted, change parent.isdeleted = 1 and
the parent is One to many table, so every time delete the parent table will also delete the same id items(trigger child table after update parent ). and trigger the insert record in the recycle table(triggered after update parent).

When deleting the child table, also trigger insert record in the recycle table

so when delete my parent table will trigger the child's trigger

when I delete parent table will show:

```
---------------------------------------------
parent_id      child_id         from
---------------------------------------------
 1              (2,3,4)         parent
 1                  2           child
 1                  3           child
 1                  4           child
```

I only want first row.

my trigger for parent:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `after_recorditems_update`;
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `after_recorditems_update` 
AFTER UPDATE ON `sn_recorditems` 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 

UPDATE sn_recordlog SET is_deleted = new.is_deleted WHERE new.id = `recordid`; 

INSERT INTO sn_recycle(deleted_at,recorditem_id,log_id,from_table_name) VALUES(new.time,new.id,(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(sn_recordlog.id SEPARATOR', ') as id FROM sn_recordlog WHERE new.time= sn_recordlog.time), 'sn_recorditems'); 

END
```

my trigger for child:

```
BEGIN
INSERT INTO
sn_recycle(deleted_at,recorditem_id,log_id,from_table)
VALUES(new.time, new.recordid, new.id, 'sn_recordlog');
END
```

Comment: Provide complete sample code for 2nd trigger. Add CREATE TABLE for all tables. Add INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE pack and desired intermediate and final data state for all tables.

Comment: Its not clear what your table structures are. "when I delete parent table will show:"? What table am I looking at, is that the table prior to the trigger? You can simply add from=parent if thats the case.